# Pearson correlation matrix in Python

Tags: python

I'm characterizing biological samples in infrared spectroscopy (mid infrared region) and the resulting data is used in predictive models, for disease prediction. I'm now working the spectrum data using supervised learning and the first step is to prepare the data (smoothing, peak finding, peak filtering, etc) and now I have a matrix of 93x1 (the dependent variables, or the disease/not disease label), where 93 are the number of samples, and a matrix of 93x210, where 210 are the number of wavelenghts where I can find the pre-filered absorption peaks. From these 210 wavelenght I need to extract the features (absorption peaks) that I'll feed into my model. For this, I'm using Pearson correlation matrix in python where the header is the 210 xi wavelenghts. I want to find correlations between absortion peaks at 'xi wavelenght' and samples. The issue is that the resulted matrix gives me '1' everywhere

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie in python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

df2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['20191201-Peaks.xlsx']),header=None, Index=None)

df2.columns=['Label_0_1','Sample',1700.105,...,1500.49]

print (df2.dtypes)

Label_0_1          object
Sample             object
1700.105           float64
1699.141           float64
1698.177           float64
                    ...   
1504.35            float64
1503.38            float64
1502.42            float64
1501.45            float64
1500.49            float64
Length: 210, dtype: object

df2.shape
(93, 210)

import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(150,150))
cor = df2.corr(method='pearson')
cor

[![correlation matrix][1]][1]
```

Comment: Provide a small dataset showing the problem, such as `df = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['T', 'F', 'F', 'T'], 'Sample': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1700.0: [1., 2, 1, 1], 1500.0: [0., 1, 1, 0.]})`.  This example actually works, giving correlations between 1700 and 1500 as `[[1, 0.577],[0.577, 1]]`.  To correlate against labels you will need to convert the label column to bool with something like `df.Label_0_1 = df.Label_0_1.map({'disease': True, 'not disease': False})`.